# Derivative of exponential with function argument

Tags: derivatives, induction, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I am trying to derive an expression for the derivative of an exponential. Here is the task phrased as a problem

> For the function $g(x) = \exp(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is real valued and continuously differentiable for all derivatives, what is a general expression for the $N$th derivative of $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$?
>
> Also, assuming $f(x)|_{x=0}$, what is an expression for $g^{(N)}(x)|_{x=0}$?

I think this should be a standard calculus problem, but I haven't found a clean solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

*First approach:* Using the principle of induction, one can prove that the $k$th derivative of $g(x)$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
g^{(k)}(x) = H_{k}(x) \exp(f(x)), \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

where $H_k(x)$ is defined recursively through

\begin{equation}
H_{k+1}(x) = H'_{k}(x) + f'(x) H_{k}(x), \qquad \qquad (2)
\end{equation}
for $k\geq 0$ and where $H_0(x) = 1$.

Attempting a generating function approach, we can define $F(x, y) \equiv \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} y^{\ell} H_{\ell}(x)$. (2) can then be written as the PDE

\begin{equation}
\big(1- y f'(x)\big)F(x, y)- y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x, y) = 1,
\end{equation}

which is not really helpful since the boundary conditions are not fully specified. That is, although we have $F(x, 0) = H_0(x) =1$ computing $F(0, y)$ requires that we know $H_k(0)$ which is what we are trying to find.

*Second approach:* Iterating (2), one can show that for $k\geq0$, $H_{k+1}(x)$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
H_{k+1}(x) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{k} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{\ell}\left(f'(x) H_{k-\ell}(x)\right),
\end{equation}

for but it is not clear what this approach buys us.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will get a sum of products of derivatives of $f$ with the number of total derivatives in each product is $n$, but I don't know if there is a general formula for the coefficients ...

So something like
$$
g^{(n)}(x) = g(x) \sum_{\substack{(k_1,\dots,k_n)\in\mathbb{N}^n\\k_1+\dots+k_n = n}} c_{k_1,\dots,k_n} \prod_{j=1}^n f^{[k_j]}(x)
$$
where $f^{[0]} = 1$ and $f^{[k]} = f^{(k)}$ if $k>0$. You can verify this formula by your recursive formula for example.

Comment: Yep the $n$th derivative of $g(x)$ can be expressed as a sum over partitions of $n$. I didn't mention this in the question because I was actually hoping for a different approach, and I didn't want to bias the answers. Still, thanks for making this explicit

Comment: Perhaps the good question is why do you need such formula, or what information do you need to get from that formula?

Comment: Enumerating partitions gets complicated when $N$ is large, and I want a way to numerically to compute $H_{N}(0)$ for $N=100$ without having to define all sets of $\{k_i\}$ that satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^{N}k_i = N$. P.S. After playing around with this for a few days, I am now not as sure as I was when I wrote this question that there is another way.

Comment: Yes, if you want an analytical solution, just by writing the case N=3 and N=4 will make you understand that you really have all the terms of the form $\prod_{j=1}^{n}f^{[k_j]}(x)$.